# How to make Qt Proxy server

Tags: c++, qt, proxy, server

I would like to develop HTTP or SOCKS Proxy server, therefore i would like to know are these functionality already implemented in Qt Libraries??
if so, could you please direct me in the right path or give me an example ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Stackoverflow is not about find whole solution. search develop and if there was an error ask question. Maybe search about Boost. you can find example of what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Up to now there aren't http server or proxy functions. Qt has only got a nice http client object.
To embed an http server component in my Qt application I'm using poco libraries.  They are very nice and easy to use.